# Почему не удается сместить таблицу вниз?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, не удается сместить таблицу вниз, на 30 px
Margin и padding не срабатывает. Речь идет о проблеме при заходе с мобильного в горизонтальном положении.

Сам виновник: `https://aviareysi.ru/new_york.php`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте! Потому что Вы не можете применять свойства margin и padding к тегу строки таблицы `<tr>`. Для этого пришлось бы прописывать для него `display: block`.

Вариант решения: для нужной ширины экрана через media queries пропишите свойства для тегов `<th>` по принципу:

```
tr th {padding-top: 50px;}
```

Так вы добавите верхний отступ для самих ячеек таблицы.

Comment: Спасибо большое!